# Get current used (allocated) memory programmatically in iOS

Tags: ios

How to get current used (allocated) memory programmatically in iOS?

Comment: Disk or RAM? Be specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this with the help on instruments there you will find allocations for each and every objects in the memory.